# Why am I having "Time step too small" error for this circuit in LTspice?

Tags: ltspice

When I run this circuit I get the following error:

[image]

Unless I set R4 to around 1 Ohm the problem persists. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: can you offer more information about your simulation settings?

Comment: The simulation settings are default settings.

Comment: Nobody is Perfect – Not Even a Programmer or Spice. What version?

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 Jan 4 2019 update

Comment: Try other options that affect division by 0, in settings. It's a step function at t=0 and thereis a convergence error. It also seems to be a common problem for many situations.  I never use LTSpice add a 1pF cap.

Comment: @SunnyskyguyEE75 VerbalKint's comment solved the issue

Answer (score 2):

**Think** about what happens in this circuit.

You made the current of B2 dependent on the current through R1.

Let's say 1 A is flowing through R1 so B2 wants to push 50 A up.

It is unclear how the direction of the current through R1 is defined, is left-to-right 
the positive current or not?

It is possible that the 50 A that B2 pushes up, **increases** the current through R1.
So B2 will multiply that change by 50 and push even more current up so the current through R1 increases even more.

Have you heard of feedback and specifically **positive feedback**? Because that's what I think is happening here. The simulator cannot find a solution as **there is no stable solution**.

The voltage at node 2 is getting out of hand, the simulator sees that the voltage at node 2 increases towards infinity (because the currents do the same).

You should not take the "timestep" error too literal, it is a consequence of there being no time delays (like a capacitor) in the circuit so the simulator will see too much change in a too small (actually zero) timestap. So it complains that the timestep is too small.

Try adding a - (minus) to the expression for B2: I = -50 * I(R1) and see if that helps to find a stable solution.

Comment: If I remove R4 or set R4  to a low value like 100 Ohm, the simulator doesn't give any error.

Comment: OK, now give a reason why that is the case. Just "doing stuff" and "observing the effect" teaches you nothing. The **explanation** is what counts. Hint: it has to do with loopgain.

Comment: The open circuit input impedance of this circuit is 20Meg for this circuit. I calculated that and it is confirmed by a text book.as well. I try to do the same in simulation. If now I set B2: I = -50 * I(R1), the currents become 1.#INFA. It didn't work.

Comment: But this circuit will have a solution \$\frac{V_A -1V}{20k\Omega} + \frac{V_A}{200k\Omega} - 50*\frac{1V - V_A}{20k\Omega}=0\$ and the soution is \$ V_A = 0.998043V \$ So they must be something wrong with Bi source.

Comment: @G36 Yes it has solution on paper. I also tried F instead of B for CCCS but no luck.

Comment: I confirm the above answer which is 998 mV for \$V_2\$ and IsSpice does find a stable dc point in a few ms. Rather than sensing the current in \$R_1\$, did you try to add a 0-V source V1 for instance (+ towards \$R_1\$) and update the in-line equation with 50*I(V1)

Comment: @VerbalKint Your trick with a voltage source works.

Comment: @G36, no surprise, this is the recommended way to sense current in branches since SPICE2, euh, a few years back already : )

Comment: Glad if I could help!

Answer (score 2):

If you open up the manual at `LTspice > Circuit Elements > B. Arbitrary behavioural voltage or current sources`, then read the bullets,you'll find that the 3rd one states:

> Circuit element currents; for example, I(S1), the current through switch S1 or Ib(Q1), the base current of Q1. However, **it is assumed that the circuit element current is varying quasi-statically, that is, there is no instantaneous feedback between the current through the referenced device and the behavioral source output**. Similarly, any ac component of such a device current is assumed to be zero in a small signal linear .AC analysis.

Emphasis mine. This means that **behavioural sources** are affected by this, but not the `F` sources. This is why, whenever you have direct current reference like this, you should try and use that, instead:

[image: F-source]

The minor disadvantage for the `F` sources is that they need a `V` voltage source, or `E` source (VCVS), or `L` (inductor) as a reference for collecting the current. Fortunately, in this case, `V1` is in series with `R1`, but the current goes from the `+` input to `-`, so the `F` source has the sign changed. Othwerwise, a simple zero-valued `V` source should have been added in series with `R1` as a sensor -- which is the typical way of "collecting" current in SPICE.

Answer (score 0):

But your circuit will have a solution

$$\frac{V_A -1V}{20k\Omega} + \frac{V_A}{200k\Omega} - 50*\frac{1V - V_A}{20k\Omega}=0$$

And the solution is

$$V_A = 0.998043V$$

And If I use this library in LTspice

https://csserver.evansville.edu/~richardson/courseware/resources/LTSpice/index.html

I got exactly the same result

[image]

Comment: What is \$V_A\$? I don't see it in the original schematic or in your LTspice schematic. Is it the same as node b, since that's where you marked the voltage on the schematic?

Answer (score 0):

Break the circuit into two isolated loops. V1 and series R1 with a load R2000 with a value of the internal resistance of your CCCS, and a separate loop with your CCCS and the series R4.

This isolates the two loops with only a common ground where feedback is grounded. Write your current value of the CCSV with I(R1) extracted from the nodal current which is I(n001). You can  use the ADDTRACE menu from the graph or RAW window to get an idea of how your R1 loop parameter current values will be displayed.

That's the way to go. Isolate loops that could offer unwanted feedback.