# Adding dependant sources in LtSpice (CDCS)

Tags: simulation, ltspice, linear, mesh-analysis

I have the following schematic of the circuit, I wanted to added **I2** as a Current Dependant Current Source depending on current on in **V1** as three times the value, or, **I(I2) = 3I(V1)**

[image]

I have tried various tutorials, and used circuit element *F* and *current* both, its not working with any. There is always an error in circuit element **I2**

What can be done to achieve this result. Thanks a lot!

Comment: BTW, the official name is CCCS (current controlled current source).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the `current` element (as seen in with the `F2` browser), which is a regular current source, as opposed to a *behavioural* source, which, for current, is `bi` and `bi2`. Once you place that, the syntax changes and you can write `I=I(...)`, as the default placeholder suggests.

However, as per a [recent answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/417616/95619), the manual warns you about quasi-instantaneous current feedback, and you should use an `F` source (which is, as you guessed, displayed as `f` with `F2` browser). Once you place that, its value should be changed, just as the manual says -- and for your case, in particular -- to `V1 3`. Note that the current into `V1` goes through the `+` pin, and exits from the `-` pin, irrespective of placement, so you should take that into account with a proper sign: `V1 -3` (if that's the case). See the linked answer for an exemplifying picture.

Comment: Thanks a lot for this, this syntax helped a lot! Also when we run the program, it gives current values without specifying direction. What is the direction to be assumed ?

Comment: @jeea If it's SPICE world, assume the current goes into the pin, except when the elements have only two pins -- then the current usually enters the first and exits the second. It's just a convention for easyness in programming the matrix solver. If it's a text book and doesn't show the direction of the current, you're out of luck -- the only way to see is actually doing it: if you get the correct results, congratulations, if not, no worries, SPICE doesn't burn or explode. In this case, if it says `I(V1)`, assume from positive to negative (you have to test, anyway).

Comment: Thanks! I figured out current direction using node voltages! :)