# LTSpice current dependent current source timestep too small error

Tags: circuit-analysis, ltspice

I solved this circuit by hand.Which asks to calculate vo and Io in the circuit.

[image: Transistor circuit]

And I tried to verify results with LTSpice.

[image: LTSpice circuit]

If I change dependent current source B2's equation to I = I(R1)* 50 it gives an error like that:

[image: LTSpice error]

If I use I = I (R1) it works fine. What might be the problem here?

Comment: I think it has to do with roundings. Check what happens to V(n001) when using I = I(R1)* 20.

Comment: It has also to do with how the initial operating point is calculated. When using I = -I(B1)*50 or I = -I(V1)*50 it works nicely.

Comment: Thanks. If I use  I = -I(B1)*50 voltage it works fine. If you answer I may select it as accepted answer.

Comment: Well, it's not the answer but the solution to *"What might be the problem here?"* ... Mind to keep it unanswered till someone can explain the cause? I'm curious as well.

Comment: If you specify I(R1) alone you don't know the **direction** of the current. Make sure you get that right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you open up the manual (`F1`) and look at `LTspice > Circuit Elements > B. Arbitrary Behavioural Voltage or Current Source`, you'll see this bullet point:

> Circuit element currents; for example, I(S1), the current through switch S1 or Ib(Q1), the base current of Q1. However, **it is assumed that the circuit element current is varying quasi-statically, that is, there is no instantaneous feedback between the current through the referenced device and the behavioral source output**. Similarly, any ac component of such a device current is assumed to be zero in a small signal linear .AC analysis.

What you have there is a direct feedback which violates the above condition. If, instead of behavioural sources, you use primites such as VCVS and CCCS, everything works:

[image: bla]

For the CCCS, I have used `V1`, for comodity, since it's already there, otherwise you would have had to add a zero-valued voltage source in series with `R1` (with correct polarity).

As a side note, in your schematic, you're labeling the ground net with `C`, which can be done, but it's completely useless. IIRC, except the ground, naming the same net more than once means LTspice will use the latest label.

Also see [this answer](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/a/418043/95619), it's the same.