# timestep too small error with non-linear capacitor - how to handle possible discontinuous points

Tags: capacitor, thermal, non-linear

I am using LT spice to simulate a thermal problem involving a phase-change material (a paraffin).
[[image: thermal simulation1]

with the paraffin modeled as a non-linear capacitor and resistor (the capacitor represents the heat capacity, the resistor the thermal conductivity:
[image: Paraffin simulation block]
Note: the thermal resistance is simulated as a voltage-controlled current source because a normal resistor can't handle if() statements in its value, even in parameters.

For thermal simulations, the voltages in the circuit equate to temperatures in Kelvin and current equates to heat-flow. (See, for instance, [Learn LTSpice: A Tutorial](https://learn-ltspice.weebly.com/thermal.html)
The non-linear capacitor has the equation

```
Q = {PCM_mass_g} * if(
    V(Heat_In) <= ({Tm} - ({epsilon}/2)), 
    (x*{Cps}),
    if(
        V(Heat_In)>=({Tm}+({epsilon}/2)
      ), 
      ({Cps}*{Tm}+{Hfus}*{Cpl}*(x-{Tm})),
      (
        ({C3}*((x-{deltaTc})**3)) + ({C2}*((x-{deltaTc})**2)) +({C1}*(x-{deltaTc}))+{C0}
      )
    )
)
```

epsilon is a small band around the melting point. Below temperature = (Tmelting - epsilon/2) the thermal capacity has the value for a solid; above (Tmelting + epsilon/2) it has another value for the liquid form, and within the epsilon band it is a complex polynomial that describes the heat of fusion for the material.

The equation should be reasonably continuous, at least it is in the spreadsheet:

[image: Spreadsheet heat capacity calculations]

But whenever the simulation voltage V(a) hits (Tmelting-epsilon/2) LTSpice throws a "timestep too small" error.

I will be most grateful for any suggestions as to how to get around this!

Comment: Normally I throw in small, negligible resistors here and there so things do not have to happen instantly and there is something to provide some give and take up slack in the system. Without them, you often have unstoppable force versus immovable object contradictions where things have to happen both instantly and not at all.

Comment: What's the .SUBCKT? The complete model would be a big help.

Comment: There isn't a SUBCKT per se. Just the "Q=..." definition. The current source is "I=(V(Heat_In)-V(Heat_Out))*((if((V(Heat_In)>{Tm}),{tcl},{tcs})*{PCM_area_m2})/{PCM_depth_m})"

Comment: That looks scary. I haven't ran your formula, but did you make sure it's the integrated version of the desired result? The manual (`LTspice > Circuit Elements > C`) clearly says "*LTspice will compile this expression and symbolically **differentiate** it with respect to all the variables, finding the **partial derivative's** that correspond to capacitances*" ([more on this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/380581/95619)). I would use that expression in a `bi` source with a unity value capacitor in parallel (and `1G` resistor), then take that voltage to `Q=` (+ maybe a small cap across).

Comment: Also take care of [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/q/427176/95619).

Comment: That could be part of the problem. If I remove the formula resistor and put in a fixed with a high enough value, or replace the non-linear cap with a fixed, it works fine. Seems that I can have one or the other, but not both.